# How to calculate the biofertilizer demand of a farm?

Tags: agriculture

I would like to calculate the demand for biofertilizer for 5 farms based on their size. The farms have the following sizes: 50, 70, 90, 100, and 120 hectares (ha). Is it possible to estimate this value? I believe we need to assume a rate of application per hectare, correct? This average fertilizer application rate can vary depending on the type of crops, soil conditions, and other agronomic factors. However, I have no information about the farms other than their size. Any ideas on how to calculate this?

Thank you very much!

Comment: i do not think it is possible to answer yor question with the current information,different parts of a sinle farm might need different quantity of fertilizer depending on the quality of the soil and other factors.